# Why gradle-test-kit-7.5.1.jar does not exist?

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I cleaned my hard disk because it was full, and I deleted also the `./gradle/caches` folder. Now, one React Native project gives the following error:

Note: It cannot find: `gradle-test-kit-7.5.1.jar`

```js
[{
    "resource": "/Volumes/code/projects/mobile/appName/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#4",
    "code": "0",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The project cannot be built until build path errors are resolved",
    "source": "Java",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 1
},{
    "resource": "/Volumes/code/projects/mobile/appName/node_modules/react-native-gradle-plugin",
    "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#4",
    "code": "964",
    "severity": 8,
    "message": "The container 'Project and External Dependencies' references non existing library '/Users/userName/.gradle/caches/7.5.1/generated-gradle-jars/gradle-test-kit-7.5.1.jar'",
    "source": "Java",
    "startLineNumber": 1,
    "startColumn": 1,
    "endLineNumber": 1,
    "endColumn": 1
}]
```

What I've tried:

- Use other Gradle Plugin Version and Gradle Version
- Clean the project: In Android Studio, go to "Build" -> "Clean Project" to clean the build artifacts.
- Rebuild the project: In Android Studio, go to "Build" -> "Rebuild Project" to rebuild the project from scratch.
- Invalidate caches and restart: In Android Studio, go to "File" -> "Invalidate Caches / Restart" and select "Invalidate and Restart". This will clear the Android Studio caches and restart the IDE.
- Delete Gradle cache: Close Android Studio and delete the Gradle cache manually. You can do this by running the following command in your terminal or command prompt: `rm -rf ~/.gradle/caches`
- Sync Gradle files: Open your project in Android Studio and click on the "Sync Project with Gradle Files" button to synchronize your Gradle configuration.

Thus the 7.5.1 folder was regenarated with everything inside, but, without the `gradle-test-kit-7.5.1.jar`

Additional notes:

- The `generated-gradle-jars` folder has:

  - `gradle-api-7.5.1.jar`
  - `gradle-kotlin-dsl-extensions-7.5.1.jar`
    but not: `gradle-test-kit-7.5.1.jar`
- `package.json` has as dependencie:

  - `"react-native-gradle-plugin": "^0.71.19",`
    and in `node_modules` it gives the above error.
- When I uploaded the app in google play store the pre-launch report gave:
  `java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load script. Make sure you're either running Metro (run 'npx react-native start') or that your bundle 'index.android.bundle' is packaged correctly for release.`

Comment: Have you tried to to build with `clean --refresh-dependencies`?

Comment: The path that it's looking for the file suggests that this is not a downloaded artifact, but a generated one, there might be some task in your project that generates this file, but I have no idea which one.

Comment: @yahorbarkouski Yes, I did use `clean --refresh-dependencies`! I forgot to mention it. Thank you!