# How can I restore a file from Macintosh HD/private/var/folders/n_ that android/build.gradle ask for?

Tags: java, android, macos, gradle

I was on low storage memory with my MacBook so I deleted some files... Now one of my React Native projects, in `android/build.gradle` gives me a red tilde at line 1. When I hover over it, I get the following message:

```js
Could not run phased build action using connection to Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip'.
The specified initialization script '/var/folders/n_/yd13xnrj4cxbvk7yvrz84m1w0000gp/T/d146c9752a26f79b52047fb6dc6ed385d064e120494f96f08ca63a317c41f94c.gradle' does not exist.Java(0)
```

At first, I thought it was an android error, so I tried to solve it by cleaning rebuilding etc. Check here other questions on StackOverflow:

- [Why the initialization script … .gradle does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76553916/why-the-initialization-script-gradle-does-not-exist)
- [Why gradle-test-kit-7.5.1.jar does not exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76434259/why-gradle-test-kit-7-5-1-jar-does-not-exist)

This time, I uninstall and reinstall Java, and restarted the MacBook, but nothing changed.

I'm stuck with this for weeks now. I used to think that fortunately the app is not yet uploaded in Google Play, so I could create a new one and copy all the code in there. But now that I see that the missing file is in a private MacBook folder, I think that maybe I need to reinstall macOS. Does anyone know what I should do?